# Spark Event Logs HDFS consistency

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm running into this odd issue where the lengths of Spark event logs are not being updated properly. For example we will look at file `application_1551818805190_0006_1.inprogress`.

When I use `hdfs dfs -ls /var/log/spark/apps/`, I see that the file is only 309 bytes:

```
[hadoop ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark  138180350 2019-03-05 22:47 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1551818805190_0004_1
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark  138184198 2019-03-05 22:57 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1551818805190_0005_1
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        309 2019-03-05 23:59 hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1551818805190_0006_1.inprogress
```

But when I get the file from HDFS (`hdfs dfs -get`) and do ls on local filesystem, then the file length is actually 85695488 bytes! I am confused because the Spark [EventLoggingListener](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/EventLoggingListener.scala#L147-L159) uses the [`.hflush()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream.html#hflush()) method which *should* make the data visible to all readers.

I'm encountering the same issue when I use the Java APIs for Hadoop. Besides opening an FSDataInputStream and using `skip` to manually calculate the actual byte length of the file, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turns out that the writer for the Spark History Server, EventLoggingListener, will 'flush' the data to HDFS, but the client will only flush if a new block has been allocated.